# Embedding RTMP stream from local server into HTML

Tags: html, jwplayer, rtmp

I am trying to create a page to display a stream that is being created from OBS, and being streamed to a local Linux server with nginx.  I followed [this](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) guide to set up the nginix server, but I am having trouble playing the stream back in html.  I am able to play the stream back through VLC, but would like to create a page to embed it with.

I am using JWPlayer, and get a "Flash plugin failed to load" when loading the page.

Here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/boostrap.min.css">
    <script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="KEYXXX";</script>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
            playerInstance.setup({
                file: "rtmp://10.0.125.160:1935/live/flv:test",
                height: 360,
                width: 640
            });
        </script>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here.  Just tried in Firefox and nothing comes up at all, Chrome I get the flash plugin error.

Comment: Do you have a web server running on your local computer and have PHP installed?

Comment: I don't, i've just been accessing the html file locally from my machine.  nginix is running on the linux box which is the 10.0.125.160 IP that OBS is streaming to.

Comment: Try running a local server in the directory of the HTML file.